# Segmentation fault 11 when appending items to a list in dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a the following code that is part of a script and it runs at the beginning of it. Running it within the entire script or just this block returns Segmentation Fault 11 (no other detail):

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if f[-3:] == 'log']
names = []
configurations = {}

for file in files:
    format_file = next(pybel.readfile('log',file))
    name = format_file.write(format='inchi')

    if name not in names:
        names.append(name)
        configurations[name] = [file]
    else:
        configurations[name].append(file)
```

The first part has no problems (based on a "print" debug)

- files are all the 'log' files in the directory, which may be up to 1500. They are outputs of a software, with sizes from 200KB to 12MB (although it size doesn't matter at this stage)
- format_file is an object from the pybel module that can be transformed to a "name" which is a string like "1S/C15H20BrClO/c1-3-5-6-10-13(17)15-11-8-7-9-12(16)14(4-2)18-15/h1,5-8,12-15H,4,9-11H2,2H3/b6-5+,8-7-/t12-,13+,14+,15+/m0/s1". There can be up to 128 different "names" in a set of files from a directory.

Then, is in the second part the code where I detect the error. Particularly, when appending a file to a list of the dictionary (again, via a "print" debug)

- creates a list of the different names.
- creates a dictionary of lists as {name1:[file1,file3], name2:[file2,file4,file4],....} (as many names and files in the directory)

When I work with relatively small amount of files that provide a small amount of names I have no problem.
But with an increasing amount of files and/or names, it gives me a "Segmentation Fault 11"

I'm working with python 3.7.6 in MacOS Mojave.

The scripts runs by directory, do not process several directories simultaneously.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post whole error message and stacktrace

Comment: That's the entire error I can see on the terminal. Is there a way to have more detail?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and make it a [mcve] please?

Comment: I just edited, although I am unable to provide all the files to reproduce the exact error. I don't know if the modifications I made are enough. And if there is another way to assist to reproduce the error

Comment: Pybel claims to be py3 only so I assume everything you're doing is with wildly out of date packages. A segfault in your parser isn't something you can fix. Time to update everything.

Comment: I'll try that. But what do you mean to be py3 only? it was working without a problem before

Comment: I have just updated everything (python, modules, the code itself). Same error. Just in case there are 2 types of pybel modules. One is PyBEL and other Pybel (which is from OpenBabel (the one I use) https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UseTheLibrary/Python.html?highlight=python